# Generation error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0 " or one of its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit, specflow, nunit-3.0

I'm getting the following error seemingly randomly when I try generate my .feature files.

Occasionally I change or alter my feature file, and this error crops up out of nowhere:

```
#error Generation error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this - I have tried adding a reference to the assembly, changing versions of SpecFlow / NUnit but nothing seems to work.

Erasing my copy of the project and pulling it from source control works initially but then it happens again.

Here is a full list of my installed packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NUnit3TestAdapter" version="3.9.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SpecFlow" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SpecFlow.NUnit" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

I'm running Visual Studio Community 17 (15.5.2), .NET 4.7.02556 and the SpecFlow extension version 2017.1.10

Answer (score 2):

What sometimes works for me is deleting the `packages` folder from the solution path, then restore nuget packages in solution and regenerate the feature files.

Sometimes this is not enough, and you also have to delete the visual studio cache.
Which is located: `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Microsoft/Visual Studio/<your VS version>/ComponentModelCache`

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, which we couldn't yet reproduce and fix.

GitHub Issue: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/857

Comment: Should be reproducible by downloading the latest copy of Visual Studio 17 and installing the packages I have listed here. Shortly after modifying the tests, the issue crops up.

Comment: Since May I wasn't able to reproduce it on any of my machines. And I got projects from users where it happened regulary. Known workaround is to use the MSBuild integration. Please see the issue for more information about that.

Comment: There is a workaound listed on http://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/ Which is linked from the issue mentioned above. all you need to do is add to your csproj. first steps fixed for me didn't need to do optional stuff

Comment: For now I have reverted back to using Specflow version 1.9.0.77 and haven't had problems for awhile!

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to remove the existing `.feature.cs` file(s) and then regenerate them.
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.5.1 and the following SpecFlow versions:

```
SpecFlow Version:2.2.0.0
SpecFlow Generator Version:2.2.0.0
```

The followin github thread, gave me the clues:
[Visual Studio 2017 Generation error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.1.0.0](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/issues/857)

Answer (score 1):

It's a Microsoft package issue. This solution worked for me. Issue disappeared and now builds successfully.

In your `Azure Build Pipeline` > `NuGet tool installer` step, change `Version of NuGet.exe to install` to a newer version, like 5.4.0.

Check Nuget's latest `ReleasedAndBlessed` version at https://dist.nuget.org/tools.json.

Answer (score 0):

Updating on the latest Visual Studio version resolve this issue for me.

*OS: macOS 10.15.1*